# ERROR [JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render`

Tags: nextjs, xm-cloud, jss-rendering-sdk

We are running Next.js JSS app using XM Cloud docker setup, our `localhost:3000` site is loading, but when we are trying to run Experience Editor it is giving 2 erros.

On First Try we are getting below error:

```
A Sitecore.JavaScriptServices application was not found for the path {itempath}. You should ensure that:
* You have applied a Sitecore configuration patch for the application (see App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ExampleApp.config.example)
> * The path represents a Route
* The Route item is a descendant of an App item
```

If I change the URL with query string **sc_site to sc_jssapp** it is giving us below error

```
2836 06:24:55 ERROR [JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render`
2836 06:24:55 ERROR Unable to connect to the remote server
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Source: System
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.RenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3000
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

**We have already checked JSS_Editing Secret in .env file and Sitecore config.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make request from Sitecore container. `localhost` on the Sitecore container is not equal to `localhost` on your local machine.

[image]

`Localhost` inside container is this container address.
You can't request from the Docker container your sites that are hosted on your machine. What you can do: setup rendering host container inside your Docker network and change `http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render` to the address of your rendering host container, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render`

Comment: Thanks I am able to resolve both the issues by changing http://localhost:300 to http://rendering:3000 and also sc_site querystring param is also working fine by changing  app item template and home item template to route template in jss

Comment: One caveat to this diagram is that you actually **can** access your machine localhost from containers network, it just has to be with the host `host.docker.internal`

Comment: @BenSewards

Yes, for a major part of containers. But it doesn't work for CM container out of the box!

You need to do a little trick to achieve it: https://exdst.com/posts/20230525-host-docker-internal-sitecore-containers

Comment: That's informative, I can confirm that I cannot ping it within my local CM on v4.22.1 still, but the node rendering host works.

Comment: @BenSewards
Yes, it should be the default behavior for all containers according the Docker documentation. But for some reason, it doesn't. And I didn't find the root, of why some containers have this issue host.docker.internal. The easy way was to path hosts file